# HighchartsのTooltipをマウスオーバなしで表示したい

Tags: javascript, highcharts

HighchartsのTooltipについて知恵をお借りしたいのですが、
scatterのグラフを表示しているのですが、表示点が200近くあり
何がどこにあるのか一見ではわかりにくい状況です。
Tooltipを表示しているので、探せば見つかるのですが、グラフを一見して
すぐ見たい点の位置がわかるように、
例えばある一つの点についてはTooltipを常時表示しておくという設定は可能なのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: tooltip を複数表示する、という事でしょうか？

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます！

複数表示というより、常に固定で一点のtooltipを表示できればと考えてます。

Answer (score 2):

chart.event.renderメソッドに特定ポイントのツールチップ表示処理を設定することで可能です。

```
Highcharts.chart('container3', {
chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
        // グラフ描画直後の処理
        render: function(){
            // 特定データポイントのツールチップを表示する
            var p = this.series[0].points[3];
            this.tooltip.refresh(p);
        }
    }
}, //...
```

詳細は、[Highcharts Maniacs](https://highchartsmaniacs.com/2018/07/05/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%95%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)サイトを参照下さい。